# How can i specify path of the assembly when using Import-Module

Tags: c#, powershell, sharepoint, .net-assembly, import-module

I have a `Solution.dll` which has methods to open SharePoint Online Management Shell and do operations as mentioned [here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Run-SharePoint-Online-8d1d0a3b). when I do that, I sometimes happen to get  exception that,

```
Could not load type 'Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.TenantManagement.SPOConditionalAccessPolicyType' from assembly 'Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.Client.Tenant, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c'.
```

The problem is that I have a old version of `Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.Client.Tenant.dll` in the same directory where my `Solution.dll` is. And it does not have `SPOConditionalAccessPolicyType` class. Whereas the 'C:\Program Files\SharePoint Online Management Shell\Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell\Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.Client.Tenant.dll' has the class.

So, When I want to access Online Management Shell, I want the solution to load the tenant dll which is there in the 'Online Management Shell' folder instead of loading the dll in my project folder.

Tried giving the following,

```
InitialSessionState iss = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault();
iss.ImportPSModule(new string[2] { "C:\\Program Files\\SharePoint Online Management Shell\\Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell\\Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell.dll",
                                   "C:\\Program Files\\SharePoint Online Management Shell\\Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell\\Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.Client.Tenant.dll" });
```

but had no luck. Still was getting 'Could not load type...' error.

Removing old version dll may not be my solution since I need it there for different purpose. How can I specify the required dll's path which should be loaded always irrespective of the existence of assembly.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this by using a module manifest:

```
New-ModuleManifest -Path '.\MyManifest.psd1' -RequiredAssemblies 'C:\Program Files\SharePoint Online Management Shell\Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell\Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.Client.Tenant.dll'
```

And then use `Import-Module`:

```
Import-Module -Name '.\MyManifest.psd1'
```

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work. Because I need to give a (different) path for a particular assembly dll when loading a module. Is that possible ?

Comment: @ShenPrabu you'd have to look at that module's manifest file and see if it's loading the DLLs that way and just replace that path.

Comment: Even when I gave this, priority was given for the assembly which is parallel to the solution (i.e The dll which is in the same path as solution.dll).

Answer (score 0):

You could simply write the following in Powershell.

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("PATH TO ASSEMBLY")
```

Please refer to this article from Microsoft [msdn.microsoft.com](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly_methods(v=vs.110).aspx) and have a look at the Load methods